# Shell equivalent of Perl's die

Tags: bash, zsh, exit-code

Is there a shell equivalent (in either bash or zsh) of Perl's `die` function?

I want to set the exit code and print a message in a single line. I know I can make my own simple function but I'm kind of hoping for a built in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In bash, is there an equivalent of die "error msg"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868818/in-bash-is-there-an-equivalent-of-die-error-msg)

Comment: Yep, this basically is a duplicate. I didn't find that when searching through though.

Comment: Unfortunately, the search sucks. Try Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you need both 
`echo` and `exit`

Answer (score 2):

Just make a `shell` function like this :

```
die() {
    [[ $1 ]] || {
        printf >&2 -- 'Usage:\n\tdie <message> [return code]\n'
        [[ $- == *i* ]] && return 1 || exit 1
    }

    printf >&2 -- '%s' "$1"
    exit ${2:-1}
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
die "Oops, there's something wrong!\n" 255
```

**EXPLANATIONS**

- the first argument is the needed message, the second optional argument is the return code :
- `${2:-1}` is a bash [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) : it `exit 1` if the second argument is missing
- in [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), `1` is the same as `FALSE` (1 => 255)
- in modern [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), `die() { }` is preferred as oldish `function die {}`
- redirecting **STDERR** to **STDOUT** like Maxwell does, is not the best practice, instead, I redirect to **STDERR** directly (like `perl` does)
- if you want to use it in *interactive shell*, put this in `~/.bashrc` and then `source ~/.bashrc`
- if you want to use it in scripts, you can `source ~/.bashrc` in your script or put it manually.
- `[[ $- == *i* ]]` test whether you are in interactive shell or not

Comment: I already noted in the question that I know can make a function.

Comment: OK, but my implementation is something really complete, robust and usable. Moreover, I avoid you many pitfalls seen in other posts. =)

Comment: And I'll probably use it, but technically didn't answer the question ;-)

Comment: That was effectively already said to make a function, but I give you how to do it =) Completeness =)