# How to define a "die" shell function?

Tags: shell, zsh

Note: this is *not* a duplicate of [In bash, is there an equivalent of die "error msg"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868818/in-bash-is-there-an-equivalent-of-die-error-msg) , as illustrated at the end of this post.

Consider the shell function

```
foo () {
    echo "testing..." 1>&2
    return 1
    echo "should never reach this point" 1>&2
}
```

The following shows `foo`'s expected behavior:

```
% foo || echo $?
testing...
1
```

I would like to encapsulate the functionality shown in the first *two* lines of `foo` in a function `die`, so that the definition of `foo` could be reduced to

```
foo () {
    die 1 "testing..."
    echo "should never reach this point" 1>&2
}
```

...while still preserving its original behavior.

My interest is primarily `zsh`, but would also be interested in answers suitable for `bash` and/or `/bin/sh` scripts, if they're different.

---

BTW, this won't work:

```
die () {
    local exit_code=$1
    shift
    echo "$*" 1>&2
    exit $exit_code
}
```

If one ran from the command line a version of `foo` that used this `die`, the result would be to kill one's current shell (at least this is the result I get when I try something similar).  This is why this question is *not* a duplicate of [In bash, is there an equivalent of die "error msg"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868818/in-bash-is-there-an-equivalent-of-die-error-msg).  At any rate, the answer to that other question won't satisfy my requirements here.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, I don't think what you want is possible. You can't return from a function simply by calling another function. This might be close to what you want, though:

```
die () {
    echo "${*:2}" 1>&2
    return $1
}

foo () (      # Parentheses, not braces, to enclose the body
    set -e
    die 1 "testing..."
    echo "Shouldn't reach here" 1>&2
)
```

When `die` returns with status 1, the `set -e` causes the current shell to exit. However, the body of `foo` started a new subshell, so that's what exits, returning control to the shell that called `foo`. However, there are two glaring problems:

1. `set -e; die...` is no shorter than `echo...; return 1`
2. Making the body of `foo` a subshell will prevent any variables set in that function from being visible to the caller.

Comment: The first problem you mention is only an artifact of the toy example; in a real function there are typically several calls to `die`, for which one `set -e` will suffice.  The second problem is far more serious, since one of the main advantages of using a function, rather than a shell script, is precisely the fact that functions can modify that current shell's environment.

Answer (score 0):

As of zsh 4.3.4, you can use throw/catch syntax. I find it much less problematic than old school 'set -e' or exit for error handling. Just make sure you do "autoload -U throw catch" to get access to them. Check out "man zshcontrib" for the details.