# How do I assert something in bash, print a useful error message, and then still fail (without necessarily exiting)?

Tags: bash

Without installing anything on a barebones bash, is there a simple and clear way to:

- test a value
- print out a message if it's not what you want
- still fail, but without exiting the window/shell

Note: unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868818/in-bash-is-there-an-equivalent-of-die-error-msg), I don't want `exit` here because that ends the window/shell. I just want to return `false` the way `test` would, and let the context determine how it wants to handle that.

Currently, I've got:

```
[[ -n "$some_val" && -n "$other_val"]] || {echo "Unable to retrieve xxx from yyy"; false}
```

that's kind of a wtf to read, but then this is more verbose than I'd like for such a simple assertion:

```
if test -n "$some_val" && test -n "$other_val"; then
  echo "Unable to retrieve xxx from yyy"
  false
fi
```

What I'd really love would be to have something like:

```
test -n "$some_val" -m "some_val missing" && test -n "$other_val" "other_val missing"
```

or:

```
[[ -n "$some_val" && -n "$other_val" ]] || fail "Unable to retrieve xxx from yyy"
```

Comment: I'd hardly call the `if` statement (significantly) more verbose. You traded `||` for some extra keywords. By the way, you can simply use `false` instead of making up a static test to fail. You can also just define a simple `fail` function that prints its argument and returns 1.

Comment: TIL about `false`. Thanks, that's quite helpful.

Comment: `(...)` is spawning a subshell - you don't need do do that.

Comment: What's wrong with `test -n "$some_val" || {echo "some_val missing"; exit;} ;  test -n "$other_val" || {echo "other_val missing"; exit}` in place of what you say you want - `test -n "$some_val" -m "some_val missing" && test -n "$other_val" "other_val missing"`?

Comment: The problem is that `exit` closes the shell, which I definitely don't want.

Comment: Well - what do you want? If it's just a meessage then don't exit

Comment: OP wants a `fail` command that outputs an error message but still has a non-zero exit status. (It would encapsulate the compound command in your updated comment.)

Comment: thsats just echo

Comment: Edited to remove the subshells — I forgot I could use `&&` inside of `[[]]`. That said, is there another way to group boolean expressions other than subshells?

Comment: `[[ foo ]] && [[ bar ]]`

Comment: This always fails: `[[ -n "$var1" ]] && [[ -n "$var2" ]] || echo "fail" && false` unless I group the last two: `[[ -n "$var1" ]] && [[ -n "$var2" ]] || (echo "fail" && false)`

Comment: That's not how to group the last 2. It'd be `{ echo "fail";  false; }`. The way you wrote it it'd spawn a subshell and if your tests failed, echo would be called and if echo succeeded then `fail` would be called.

Comment: Ah, that's very handy. Thanks!

Comment: Also see [BashFAQ/101 - Common utility functions (warn, die)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/101).

Answer (score 7):

```
die() { rc=$?; (( $# )) && printf '%s\n' "$*" >&2; exit $(( rc == 0 ? 1 : rc )); }

do_something || die "explanation of how it failed"
```

Let's break this down:

- Capturing `$?` at the top of the function lets us get the exit status that caused the function to be invoked.
- Checking `$#` lets us log an error message only if there actually was an error to log.
- If we *do* log a message, we send it to stderr so our message doesn't get mixed in with output (and potentially directed to a file or pipeline where the user will never see it).
- `$(( rc == 0 ? 1 : rc ))` causes us to exit with status 1 if `die` was called when `$?` didn't reflect a failure, or the prior exit status otherwise.

If you don't want to exit the shell interpreter but just want to pass the exit status along, change the `exit` to `return`.

Comment: Unfortunately when I try this, the `exit` inside of the function still exits the shell I'm in, which is not what I want. I just want it to fail the command.

Comment: See the last paragraph, which tells you to change the `exit` to `return` if that's what you want.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Brilliant, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The function you want is trivial to define:

```
fail () {
    printf '%s\n' "$1" >&2
    return "${2:-1}"
}

test -n "$some_val" || fail "Value is empty"
```

(The definition is overly general, so that you can provide an explicit exit status for the function if `1` isn't desired, for example, `complicated_test || fail "Failed, preserving exit status" $?`. The `$?` will contain the exit status of the command that allowed the second half of the `||` list to execute.)

Comment: Missing a `>&2` on the `printf`, no?

Comment: Eh, probably. OP wasn't concerned about the distinction, though they should be.

Comment: Well, I've definitely learned a few things from asking this question, so I'm glad I did. That said, defining a function every time I want to use this (e.g., every GH Action step) seems like it adds more faff than it's worth — I was hoping there was some builtin that I was missing. There was, actually (`false`, which eliminates the `test -n ""` that I was doing), but it doesn't get me as far as I would like.

Answer (score 1):

[Bash Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)'s `${foo:?msg}` already does this, sort of...

`${parameter:?word}`

> If parameter is null or unset, the expansion of word (or a message to that effect if word is not present) is written to the standard error and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

That `exits` can throw some odd behavior, though, so be aware.

It's easy to test these with `:` (which is just a synonym for `true`, which returns a success, but *accepts arguments* it ignores, letting the interpreter parse them and very possibly fail... but a fail *exits* and will never even bother to execute `:`, aborting the entire pipeline, so you really can't intuitively test its results.

Observe:

```
$: : ${some_val:?unset} ${other_val:?oopsie whoops...} && echo vars ok
bash: some_val: unset

$: some_val=1
$: : ${some_val:?unset} ${other_val:?oopsie whoops...} && echo vars ok
bash: other_val: oopsie whoops...

$: other_val=2
$: : ${some_val:?unset} ${other_val:?oopsie whoops...} && echo vars ok
vars ok
```

You'd think you could use `||` to catch the error, but it doesn't work, because a fail exits the pipeline entirely.

```
$: : ${some_val:?unset} ${other_val:?oopsie whoops...} || echo not executed
bash: other_val: oopsie whoops...
```

The echo is in fact not executed. To get it to fire, put the tests in a subshell -

```
$: ( : ${some_val:?unset} ${other_val:?oopsie whoops...} ) || echo executed
bash: other_val: oopsie whoops...
executed
```

The `||` is now testing the exit code from the subshell...
But at this point the construct is really no simpler than an `if` structure, and is considerably harder to read and maintain, especially for those who come after you, so... Have you really gained anything? If you put it in a script, the script exits on the fail.

```
$: cat tst
#! /bin/bash
: ${some_val:?unset} && : ${other_val:?oopsie whoops...}
date

$: ./tst
./tst: line 2: some_val: unset

$: some_val=1 ./tst
./tst: line 2: other_val: oopsie whoops...

$: some_val=1 other_val=2 ./tst
Thu Jan 26 13:10:47 CST 2023
```

For simple scripts, this may be fine, but consider carefully.

It does make it reasonably easy to implement what you wanted as a function and customize behavior, though -

```
$: cat tst
#! /bin/bash
chk() { local -n v="$1"; local msg="${2:-unset}"; ( : ${v:?$1: $msg} ); }
chk some_val;                    echo chk returned $?;
chk other_val "oopsie whoops!!"; echo chk returned $?;
date

$: ./tst
./tst: line 2: v: some_val: unset
chk returned 1
./tst: line 2: v: other_val: oopsie whoops!!
chk returned 1
Thu Jan 26 13:28:29 CST 2023

$: some_val=1 ./tst
chk returned 0
./tst: line 2: v: other_val: oopsie whoops!!
chk returned 1
Thu Jan 26 13:29:55 CST 2023

$: other_val=1 ./tst
./tst: line 2: v: some_val: unset
chk returned 1
chk returned 0
Thu Jan 26 13:30:05 CST 2023

$: some_val=1 other_val=2 ./tst
chk returned 0
chk returned 0
Thu Jan 26 13:30:16 CST 2023
```

Comment: This does require a fairly recent version of `bash`...

Comment: `${var:?NoValueFor_VarErrMsg}` was in the original Bourne Shell.  So I think it's always(?) been in bash. Glad you included this as a solution, I use it all the time. Your functionalized version is very nice! Goo luck to all.

Comment: I mostly meant namerefs. Those are more recent. :)

Comment: Ah yes, we see what we are familar with !-; . Yes, namerefs are new. Not that it mattes much anymore, `ksh` had namerefs since '93. sniff, RIP ksh93. (yes, I know its available still) . ALSO love your use of prepended variables `some_val=1 other_val=2 ./tst`. Another favorite ! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to write a verify function which wraps around the commands you are trying to run. Benefit is that it can output all the relevant details about the failed command.

```
verify_task() {

    local name="$1"
    local command=("${@:2}")
    "${command[@]}"
    local return_code=$?

    if (( $return_code )); then
        {
            echo '[ERROR]'
            [ -n "$name" ] && echo "task: '$name'"
            printf "command: "; printf "'%s' " "${command[@]}"; echo
            echo "return_code: $return_code"
        } >&2
        exit $return_code
    fi
}

some_val=123
other_val=

verify_task "check some_val exists" test -n "$some_val"
verify_task "check other_val exists" test -n "$other_val"
# [ERROR]
# task: 'check other_val exists'
# command: 'test' '-n' ''
# return_code: 1
```

With piped commands, you'll still have to exit since verify_task will only exit the subshell.

```
echo 'hello error' | verify_task "find world" grep world || exit
# [ERROR]
# task: 'find world'
# command: 'grep' 'world'
# return_code: 1
```