# forward failing exit code for echo

Tags: linux, bash, macos, sh, posix

I am writing a very basic shell script, and I want to check if a variable is set.

normally I'll just write something like

```bash
test "${FOO}" || exit
```

but I would have liked to also write a message

```bash
test "${FOO}" || echo 'set FOO' || exit
```

but now `exit` is not invoked anymore for the obvious reason that `echo` succeeded.
and yeah, I can just write `&&` or `;` after the `echo` command.

But I was wondering if there were an "enhanced" version of `echo` (or `test`) - possibly standard/very common - that could act basically like an `assert`.
Ideally I would like to write

```bash
test "${FOO}" --on-false-echo 'set FOO'
echo $? # 1
```

or something like

```bash
test "${FOO}" || echo 'set FOO' --forward-exit-code
echo $? # 1
```

is there something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868818/in-bash-is-there-an-equivalent-of-die-error-msg

Comment: Note: You cannot "just" write `&&` after the `echo` command. See [BashPitfalls/22](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3).

Comment: See [BashFAQ/101 - Common utility functions (warn, die)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/101).  With a `die` function you can do: `test "$FOO" || die 'set FOO'`

Comment: yeah, I think the more common idiom is to roll my own `die` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elegant solution:

```
test "${FOO}" || { echo 'Exit message'; exit 1; }
```

So if `${FOO}` is not set (if first condition is not met), then the whole snippet within the curly brackets `{}` will be executed.

Note that you need spaces around the curly brackets, and note the last `;`, which is also needed

Comment: *and yeah, I can just write && or ; after the echo command.*

Comment: @Paolo OP is incorrect in their belief that `&&` or `;` solves the problem. Command grouping is necessary if you are determined to use the `cmd || <multiple commands on failure>` structure rather than the recommended `if...else...fi`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `trap` here:

```bash
$ function f() { echo 'set FOO' ; return 1 ; }
$ trap f ERR
$ test "${FOO}"
set FOO
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is trying to ask. Also, the `ERR` trap is a Bash extension, and not portable to POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

> if there were an "enhanced" version of echo (or test) - possibly standard/very common - that could act basically like an assert

There is not.

> is there something like that?

No.

Do not use `||` `&&`. Use `if`.

```
if test -z "${FOO}"; then
     echo 'set FOO'
     exit 1
fi
```

Put repeatable code in a function. In bash use `-v`.

```
hastobeset() {
   local i
   for i in "$@"; do
      if [[ ! -v "$i" ]]; then
          echo "set $i"
          exit 1
      fi
   done
}
hastobeset FOO BAR
```